# tvOS - Playing uLaw sounds

Tags: objective-c, swift, tvos

I am trying to play a uLaw sound on tvOS (.au file). I know the sound file is not corrupt as putting it into Audacity makes it play without errors.

I have tried a variety of ways, from AVAudioPlayer to lower level AudioSession, etc. but none have worked.

Specifics on the audio file:
G.711 μ-law 8000kHz mono audio stream

Objective-C or Swift

**EDIT:** This is a streamed file, similar to a MJPEG stream. I am currently getting the data through NSURLSession. Not sure if this helps, but the audio is coming from an IP camera.

Answer (score 0):

A mono μ-law file at 8K plays without problems with `AVPlayer` or `AVAudioPlayer` in iOS (it should be the same in tvOS).

```
let avp = AVPlayer(URL: ulawFileURL)
avp.play()
```

It also works with AVAudioPlayer:

```
let avp = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: ulawFileURL)
avp.play()
```

*Note: if you're doing this in a Playground, you have to enable `XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.needsIndefiniteExecution = true` since the `play` method is asynchronous.*

Comment: The audio is being streamed similar to a MJPEG stream. See my edit for details.